# Instagram Scraping in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping, instagram

I want to add a feature in my project of Instagram followers.

```
<?php
    function callInstagram($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/xyz/";
    $dom = new domDocument();  
    $dom->loadHTML($result); 
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script type'); 
    ?>
```

I am using DOM to get the content from HTML: `'script type'` onwards but not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually call the `callInstagram($url)` function, otherwise your `$result` variable will be empty. The main routine should therefore begin like this (with added second line):

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/ravij28/";
$result = callInstagram($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML($result); 
[..]
```

Also, when you want to retrieve the scripts on the page, you need to use the tag name, which is just `script`, not `script type`. So, the last line of your snippet needs to read:

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
```

Comment: Do I still need the curl part?
If yes than where should I define $result = callInstagram($url)?

Comment: Yes, keep it. Just add the one line in the main routine as shown in my code snippet, before you create the DOMDocument instance.

Comment: <?php  
function callInstagram($url)

{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2))
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}
$url = "instagram.com/ravij28/";
$result = callInstagram($url);
 $dom = new domDocument(); 
 $dom->loadHTML($result); 
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
 $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script'); 
 print_r($tables);
?>
Still showing error of unexpected $result